# Rubber Fails Using XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, rubber

My document builds just fine using `xelatex`, but now I am trying `rubber` and I get the following error:

```
$ rubber --module xelatex proposal
Source path uses special characters, error tracking might get confused.
compiling proposal.tex...
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty:41: ..............................................  
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty:41: leading text:  }
```

I have no idea how to debug this, since the error appears to be in `fontspec.sty` and not in my document itself.

I don't think I'm doing anything particularly weird in my preamble either:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,oneside]{report} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,url=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\textit{My Proposal}}
\rhead{\textit{Mark A. Richman}}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Menlo}
\newfontfamily\titlefont[Scale=2.0,Ligatures=TeX]{Minion Pro}
\urlstyle{same}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the actual problem, but you should drop the usage of `fontenc` when compiling with xelatex and fontspec.

Comment: Why is that? I'm happy to remove unneeded modules :)

Comment: Fontspec selects an encoding by himself. This is EU1 (xetex) or EU2 (luatex).

Comment: Did you ever puzzle this out? Just started seeing it.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't touched LaTeX in almost a year now :(